# How to make TableLayout Responsive

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tablelayout

currently i am developing some `android` application which contains `list`.
I've made one in Mobile(handset) device.
and I want to make it `responsive` in tablets (7"-10") display. so the `header` and the `column` will look same as in mobile display.

here is the defference between 5" and 7" display:

[image: 5" display]

[image: Tablet Dispaly]

this is my current xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="reqtag"
>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:showDividers="beginning|end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Date"
            android:id="@+id/tvClaimDateReimbursementRequest"

            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:width="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvTypeRequestReimbursement"
            android:width="80dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:width="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvAmountReimbursementRequest" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tvStatusReimbursementRequest" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I've seen the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

but I still don't get it,
is there any best-practices to do things like this?

thanks

Comment: Change the tables for linear layouts: I would add a parent linenar layout (vertical) and inside: A linear layout (vertical) and under this linear layout, the recyclerview. To make it responsive, use gravity as Stas Melnychenko said. Remove the margins, give a bigger text size and use the strings.xml to add text,: Do not harcode text, it's not useful if you need to maintain the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for every header `TextView`, because `TableRow` is a `LinearLayout`.

But I believe `TableView` is not the best approach. If you describe what do you want to achieve, we could figure out better way.

Comment: Maybe something like staggered layout (RecyclerView)

Answer (score 0):

assign you tablerow layout a weightsum.. then devide and assign that weight to all your textviews equally. like:

```
<TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weight_sum="1"  >

<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2" // for five texts .2 for each
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            ......  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your table row
A layout that arranges its children horizontally. A TableRow should always be used as a child of a TableLayout. If a TableRow's parent is not a TableLayout, the TableRow will behave as an horizontal LinearLayout.

The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively **MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.**

Answer (score 0):

You should use **sp** for text and **dp** for Views.  So instead of `android:textSizes="12dp"` it should be `android:textSize="12sp"`

Look here for more details: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension